# Azure: How can I downgrade a database from P1 to S0?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to downgrade a database from P1 to S0.  Is there a setting in the Azure portal for this?  I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

PORTAL-->SELECT DATABASE -->SCALE-->CHANGE SERVICE TIER

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://manage.windowsazure.com/. Login to this using your credentials then,
click on sql databases. It will list the databases. Select the database to downgrade. Then you can see dashboard, monitor, scale... menus on the top. Select scale option. Here you can see the option to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I am using the new portal.azure.com so the options don't appear exactly like the way you mention.  However, they did lead me in the right direction.

Databases -> Select database -> Scroll down on that database blade to Usage container.  Click on Pricing box.  Then change the settings to whatever you want.

Thanks!